# Pymongo find if value has a datatype of NumberLong

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm using the Pymongo driver and my documents look like this:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5368a4d583bcaff3629bf412"),
"book_id" : NumberLong(23302213),
"serial_number" : '1122',
}
```

This works because the serial number is a string:

```
find_one({"serial_number": "1122"})
```

However, this doesn't:

```
find_one({"book_id": "23302213"})
```

Obviously its because the book_id has a datatype of NumberLong. How can execute the find method based on this datatype?

==================================================

Update:

Still can't get this to work, I can only find string values. Any advise would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried passing it a _number_ instead of a string? `find_one({"book_id": 23302213})`?

Comment: Yes I tried exactly that but it does not find anything !

Comment: What is the type of `book_id` when you inspect that dictionary in the interpreter?

Comment: try `find_one({"book_id": long(23302213)})`

Comment: No - tried this too. It still doesn't find anything.

Comment: go into the shell and execute `db.coll.find( {"book_id": NumberLong(23302213) }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure your data types are matching. MongoDB is strict about types. When you execute this:

```
find_one({"book_id": "23302213"})
```

you are asking MongoDB for documents with `book_id` equal to `"23302213"`. As you are not storing the `book_id` as type `string` but as type `long` the query needs to respect that:

```
find_one({"book_id": long(23302213)})
```

If, for some reason, you have the ID as string in your app this would also work:

```
find_one({"book_id": long("23302213")})
```

**Update**

Just checked it (MacOS 64bit, MongoDB 2.6, Python 2.7.5, pymongo 2.7) and it works even when providing an integer.

Document in collection (as displayed by Mongo shell):

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("536960b9f7e8090e3da4e594"), "n" : NumberLong(222333444) }
```

Output of python shell:

```
>>> collection.find_one({"n": 222333444})
{u'_id': ObjectId('536960b9f7e8090e3da4e594'), u'n': 222333444L}
>>> collection.find_one({"n": long(222333444)})
{u'_id': ObjectId('536960b9f7e8090e3da4e594'), u'n': 222333444L}
```

Comment: Hmm..This is what I thought. Its still can't find anything though!

Comment: I don't think the `NumberLong` type corresponds with `long`. At least if I store a number in mongodb with `long()`, I can query for it just by giving an integer. Maybe `pymongo` converts it internally if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $type:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/type/

INT is 16, BIGINT is 18

Comment: I can't seem to see how to user this find_one({"book_id":{ "$type": 18 } }) with the Pymongo driver. Is this supported ?