# Determine length of NumberLong in Python

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have some documents in my MongoDB collection, some of which contain NumberLong values :

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57e4d18df4733211b613f199"), "parentid" : "P1000016", "phone" : NumberLong("9819733299") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57e4d18df4733211b613f19a"), "parentid" : "P1000014", "phone" : "24306574|9920599404||9920840077|865" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57e4d18df4733211b613f19b"), "parentid" : "P1000017", "phone" : "25821154|25821188|" }
```

I'm importing them into my python code and extracting each number using split (if I have multiple number sets in phone) or otherwise, directly appending to a list.

But I want only those numbers in my list whose length is greater than 6.

So I tried using this:

```
#Initializing MongoDB client
client = MongoClient()

#Connection
db = client.mumbai
collection = db.mumbaiLive

for post in collection.find():
    shops.append(post) 

for shop in shops:
    phones = shop["phone"].split("|")
    for eachPhone in phones:
        if (len(eachPhone) < 6):
            pass
```

It works fine until it encounters a NumberLong value. 
When I perform

`print "len = ", len(eachPhone)`, I get

```
len =
```

I even tried converting it into string first but got the same result.

What I want : I want to skip 'pass'ing the NumberLong values using length check or any other method (like determining whether a value is NumberLong or not).

Comment: can you check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23490798/pymongo-find-if-value-has-a-datatype-of-numberlong)

Comment: Hello @Jeril. I checked that link but couldn't arrive at a proper conclusion.

Comment: You need to change your document structure and make the`phone` field an array

Answer (score -1):

Depending on your use case, you can either add a filter to your query, to only return field `phone` where the value is string by utilising [$type](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/#type)

```
client = MongoClient()
db = client.database
collection = db.collection

for document in collection.find({"phone":{"$type":"string"}}):
    print document
```

Which would 'skip' passing `phone` containing `NumberLong` value to your function.

Alternatively, if you would like to process `phone` with `NumberLong` value in a different manner you can utilise Python [isinstance](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance). See below for an example:

```
for doc in collection.find():
    if isinstance(doc["phones"], long):
        print("Number of digits: %s" % len(str(doc["phones"])))
    else:
        print("Number is not NumberLong")
```

If you are using Python 2, you have to detect `long`. If you are using Python 3, you can just detect `int` .

Comment: Not sure why this answer received a down vote. It is a complete, working answer for the question. The linked post in the comment above didn't even suggest a filtering solution, only a) differentiation of mongo shell number with python long, and b) hinting the use of $type.